# Fluid, Pagebrowse with VHS-Viewhelper

Tags: typo3, fluid

I use the VHS ViewHelper "v:page.menu.browse". So I can click through pages that are on the same level. This also works just fine. However, what is not working, that I get the navigation elements appear only if more than one page is available. I've already tried with f:count query whether more than one page is available. Unfortunately, he shows me the items still on. Does somebody has any ideas?

```
<v:page.menu.browse>
        <f:if condition="<f:count>{menu.prev}</f:count> > 1">
            <f:then>
                <li><a href="{menu.prev.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_prev"></span></a>1</li>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                <f:if condition="<f:count>{menu.prev}</f:count> > 1">
                    <f:then>
                         <li><a href="{menu.last.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_prev"></span></a>2</li>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>

                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
        <li><a href="javascript:history.back();"><span class="icondetail-icon_uebersicht"></span></a></li>
        <li><span class="icondetail-icon_mail"></span></li>
        <f:if condition="<f:count>{menu.next}</f:count> > 1">
            <f:then>
                <li><a href="{menu.next.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_next"></span></a>3</li>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
               <f:if condition="<f:count>{menu.next}</f:count> > 1">
                    <f:then>
                         <li><a href="{menu.first.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_next"></span></a>4</li>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>

                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
    </v:page.menu.browse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use tag notation within the attributes, like you have here:

```
<f:if condition="<f:count>{menu.prev}</f:count> > 1">
```

Instead you should use **inline notation**:

```
<f:if condition="{menu.prev -> f:count()} > 1">
```

or

```
<f:if condition="{f:count(subject: menu.prev)} > 1">
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. This {menu.prev -> f:count()} gives always 0 back. But why ?

Comment: @herrsaidy try to play with parentheses and apostrophes, like  `{{menu.prev} -> f:count()}` or `{'menu.prev' -> f:count()}` or both. Or try second variant and also try these additions.

Comment: if I take your suggestion, he shows me in the frontend this: {'menu.prev' -> f:count()} and this {{menu.prev} -> f:count()}

Comment: Okay, can you then debug `<f:debug>{menu.prev}</f:debug>` to see, what is inside? For me it seems, that condition will always be false, bcs `{menu.prev}` contains properties of single menu item - not the whole list of previous menu items.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
   <v:page.menu.browse>         
            <f:if condition="<f:count>{menu}</f:count> == 3">
                <f:then>
                    <li><a href="{menu.up.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_uebersicht"></span></a></li>
                    <li><span class="icondetail-icon_mail"></span></li>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <f:if condition="{menu.prev.link}">
                        <f:then>
                            <li><a href="{menu.prev.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_prev"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="{menu.up.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_uebersicht"></span></a></li>
                        </f:then>
                        <f:else>
                            <li><a href="{menu.last.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_prev"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="{menu.up.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_uebersicht"></span></a></li>
                        </f:else>
                    </f:if>
                    <f:if condition="{menu.next.link}">
                        <f:then>
                            <li><span class="icondetail-icon_mail"></span></li>
                            <li><a href="{menu.next.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_next"></span></a></li>
                        </f:then>
                        <f:else>
                            <li><span class="icondetail-icon_mail"></span></li>
                            <li><a href="{menu.first.link}"><span class="icondetail-icon_next"></span></a></li>
                        </f:else>
                    </f:if>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
        </v:page.menu.browse>
```